# docker-machine breaks docker native client on linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-machine

I am on Ubuntu and decided to use `docker-machine` to run some docker `swarm` tests. Here you execute

```
eval $(docker-machine env xxxxx)
```

and with that your native docker client points to that machine/vm. However, after the tests I wan't the docker command to point to my local docker client/daemon/whatever and executed

```
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

which is supposed to unset the environment variables. But now I get this error

> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

I've had to create a docker machine on VirtualBox called `default`, point to that machine and run my commands there. But its pretty lame since I feel like I am back on Windows and one of the reason I came to Ubuntu was better docker integration.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: You could just unset the environment variables yourself, if they're still set.  Are they?

Comment: @larsks What are the default values?

Comment: The default values are "no environment variables are set".

Comment: @larsks I've verified that they are all unset and I still get the error.

Comment: Is the docker daemon running?  Are the permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock` correct (as in, do they permit you access to the socket)?

Comment: @larsks Permission are wrong! I did a `sudo docker run hello-world` and it worked. Whats the normal level of permission for that file?

Comment: The default behavior is to only permit `root` access (because the ability to start a container is equivalent to having `root` on the host).  Anything more permissive you would have to configure yourself.  If you have questions about doing that you may want to open a new question, because these comments are growing a bit long.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just `sudo` every time I need to run a container.

Comment: You can give non-root users access by adding them to the "docker" group; see the documentation here; https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group

Answer (score 2):

unset all docker variables

```
  unset ${!DOCKER_*}
```

regarding the 'can't connect to daemon', ensure you're prepending each docker command with sudo, or to allow your current user to interact with docker use:

```
  sudo groupadd docker
  sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

restart docker and
re-login to the terminal